# i am using insert statement to insert data from oracle forms to database but its inserting 2 rows instead of one

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am using `insert` statement to insert data from oracle forms to database but instead of **one** row.. its inserting **two** rows automatically..?

I am using the following query:

```
insert into xx_book_grp3 ( BOOK_ID,AUTHOR_ID,ISBN,PAGES,PUBLISHING_DATE,BOOK_TYPE,COST,BOOK_NAME) values (xxtrn_grp3_book_id.nextval,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.AUTHOR_ID,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.ISBN,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.PAGES,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.PUBLISHING_DATE,
:XX_BOOK_GRP3.BOOK_TYPE,      
:XX_BOOK_GRP3.COST,           
:XX_BOOK_GRP3.BOOK_NAME);
commit;
```

Comment: Either you have a trigger on the table or you are calling the code twice.

Comment: i have used "On Button Pressed" Trigger On a button.. but i don't have any triggers on tables. :)

Comment: its some time ago, but  Oracle Forms insert a new row in a block by itsself when the form is saved/commited, maybe you don't need the trigger...

Comment: maybe your javascript file has been added twice - so that the button onclick even will occur twice - thus inserting twice ;) - check this ;)

Comment: Make data changes in non transactional triggers is bad technique. But it is no reason for described behavior. I guess that one record is inserted by your button trigger code and the second one by standard block processing after you press commit key (F10 on windows)

Comment: thank you all..Petr Pribyl  Pat  Turo Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

Try this to prevent duplicate insert:
-- I think you can check for existing record on author_id and isbn or even isbn only is sufficient:

```
Declare
v_count number;
Begin
Select count(*) into v_count from xx_book_grp3
  where author_id = :xx_book_grp3.author_id and isbn = :xx_book_grp3.isbn;
if v_count = 0 then
insert into xx_book_grp3 ( BOOK_ID,AUTHOR_ID,ISBN,PAGES,PUBLISHING_DATE,BOOK_TYPE,COST,BOOK_NAME) values (xxtrn_grp3_book_id.nextval,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.AUTHOR_ID,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.ISBN,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.PAGES,:XX_BOOK_GRP3.PUBLISHING_DATE,
:XX_BOOK_GRP3.BOOK_TYPE,      
:XX_BOOK_GRP3.COST,           
:XX_BOOK_GRP3.BOOK_NAME);
commit;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Also double check in your form that you havnt written insert code in pre-insert or post-insert trigger in block level or form lever...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have a primary key in your table. Please note: PK eliminates duplication.

I also suggest checking your form for any insert for the same table.
You may be have a database trigger or a database procedure which is called from by name inside any form trigger.